# How to apply context-dependent changes to numerical data in text files?

Tags: replace, text-files, batch-processing

I'm aware of a lot of batch processors that can do find-and-replace operations, but they generally can't handle numerical formulas, nor can they be made to edit only a certain part of a text file.
Specifically, I have a problem of the following form. I have a document with tons of unimportant data, and at irregular intervals it will look like this:

```
texttextexttexttext
apple [color]
texttextexttexttext
orange [number x]
texttextexttexttext
banana [number y], [number z]
texttextexttexttext
```

... and so forth, about 650 times. What I want to do is search for each instance of apple and then replace "number z" with f(x,y) if "color"=red, g(x,y) if "color"=yellow, h(x,y) if "color"=green, or leave it alone otherwise. f, g, and h are fairly simple functions - for example f(x,y)=0.1*x+2*y, rounded to the nearest integer.
I'm asking this as someone with absolutely no coding experience, but willing to try writing a script. However if someone knows of a program that can already handle such a task, that would be nice too.

Comment: If you have no coding experience then it is best to post exact samples of text, and explain what needs to be done with examples. The alternative is for someone to provide code that solves your fake example - and what usually happens then is that the next 20 replies deal with why it fails, because the real data contains things like poison characters and strings that need special handling.

Comment: Thank you foxidrive. However I'm more interested in the question of how to do it than in having a code that solves one particular example. If someone could show me a code that solved the fake example, I would appreciate that just as much as one that solved the example I'm actually working on, which is very similar. Unfortunately I can't post the original because it contains proprietary information.

Comment: The fake example reproduces the format pretty much exactly. I just changed different words to the names of fruits. Also once again I'm mainly interested in knowing how to do tasks like this, moreso than just doing this particular task.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is as regular as you suggest, it doesn't necessarily require any programming as such. You could use a suitable text editor (say, e.g., TextWrangler for Mac or Notepad++ for Windows) and apply a few regular expressions, searching for something like

```
^(apple \[red\]\n.*\norange.*\n.*\nbanana \[.*?\], \[)(number z)(\])
```

and replacing with

```
\1f(x,y)\3
```

See [RegEx101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/sC4nH6/1).

Please comment, if and as adjustment / further detail is required.

Comment: Does this require more detail?